# Validation errors not sent using redirect withInput()

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to send my validation errors to another method by using redirect

```
public function save()
    {

        //validasi input
        if (!$this->validate([
            'judul' => 'required|is_unique[komik.judul]'
        ])) {
            return redirect()->to('/komik/create')->withInput();
        }
```

this is the create() method

```
public function create()
    {
        session();
        $data = [
            'title' => 'Form Tambah Data Komik',
            'validation' => \Config\Services::validation()

        ];

        return view('komik/create', $data);
    }
```

This is a snippet of my `create.php` view form where I'm trying to validate

```
<form action="/komik/save" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <?php d($validation) ?>
                <?= $validation->listErrors();; ?>
```

this is the form
[image]

The problem is that the validation errors in `save()` is not sent to the `create()` method. But the validation errors exist in the `save()` method which I can prove by adding
`$validation = \Config\Services::validation(); dd($validation);`
in `save()`. This is what happens when I click "Tambah Data" button after I add the code
[image]

as you can see there is a validation error, it's just not sent to the `create()` method
[image]

I tried using `return view()`, this works but it creates another problem. I would like to use `return redirect()` instead.

This is my routes

```
$routes->get('/', 'Pages::index');
$routes->get('/komik/create', 'Komik::create');
$routes->get('/komik/edit/(:segment)', 'Komik::edit/$1');
$routes->post('/komik/save', 'Komik::save');
$routes->delete('/komik/(:num)', 'Komik::delete/$1');
$routes->get('/komik/(:any)', 'Komik::detail/$1');
```

What can I do to solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, apparently there's a bug with `redirect()->withInput()` in CI. You need to use `validation_errors()`, `validation_list_errors()` and `validation_show_error()` to display validation error. Also you don't need to write `$validation = \Config\Services::validation();`.
Read https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/installation/upgrade_430.html#redirect-withinput-and-validation-errors

Answer (score 1):

A. Use [Flashdata](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=flashdata#flashdata) instead.

> CodeIgniter supports “flashdata”, or session data that will only be
> available for the next request, and is then automatically cleared.

I.e:

**`save()` method.**

```php
public function save()
{
    //validasi input
    if (!$this->validate([
        'judul' => 'required|is_unique[komik.judul]'
    ])) {
        $validation = \Config\Services::validation();

        return redirect()
            ->to('/komik/create')
            ->with("redirectedErrors", $validation->listErrors())
            ->with("redirectedInput", $this->request->getVar());
    }
}
```

[`with()`](https://codeigniter4.github.io/api/classes/CodeIgniter-HTTP-RedirectResponse.html#method_with)

> Adds a key and message to the session as *Flashdata*.
>
> `public with(string $key, array<string|int, mixed>|string $message) : $this`

B. Then, modify the `create()` method to pass on the flashed data to the View.

**`create()` method.**

```php
    public function create()
    {
        return view('komik/create', [
            'title' => 'Form Tambah Data Komik',
            'validation' => \Config\Services::validation(),
            'redirectedErrors' => session()->getFlashdata("redirectedErrors") ?: "",
            'redirectedInput' => session()->getFlashdata("redirectedInput") ?? [],
        ]);
    }
```

C. Lastly, in your View file (`create.php`), you may access the passed-on data normally.

**`create.php` View file.**

```php
<form action="/komik/save" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <?php echo empty($validation->getErrors()) ? $redirectedErrors : $validation->listErrors() ?>

    <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" value="<?php echo old('first_name', array_key_exists('first_name', $redirectedInput) ? $redirectedInput['first_name'] : '') ?>"/>

</form>
```